# Laravel broadcast event to node server through redis

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io, predis

I have a laravel application where I use events to notify the clients of updates. Previously I used pusher to broadcast those events but I want to change this to redis (or anything without the need of a 3rd party like pusher). I tried to use predis and send a message like the following:

```
$redis = Redis::connection();
$redis->publish('message', 'test message');
```

This does work but I would like to broadcast events like: `event(new TestEvent())` and receive them on my node server through socket.io/redis/etc. What do I have to change to do this?

.env

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Broadcasting config:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "pusher", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_DRIVER', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over websockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
//                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_APP_USE_TLS'),
                'host' => env('PUSHER_APP_HOST'),
                'port' => env('PUSHER_APP_PORT'),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_APP_SCHEME')
            ],
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];
```

My node server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const http = require('http');
const server = http.Server(app);

const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const io = socketIO(server);

const redis = require('redis');

const port = 3000;

io.on('connection' , (socket) => {
   console.log('user connected');

   const redisClient = redis.createClient();
   redisClient.subscribe('message');

   redisClient.on('message', function(channel, message) {
       console.log(channel);
       console.log(message);

       socket.emit(channel, message);
   });

    socket.on('test1', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });
});

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('started on port: ' + port);
});
```

Comment: Did you accomplish your goal?